# ListView with more than two values

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have an object which contains the necessary data which they are four and I want to set them on a list with four `TextView` as well. I used `HashMap` with two values but can't figure it out with more than two.

`Medicine` class

```
public class Medicine {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String doctor;
    private String date;
    private String dose;

    public Medicine() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(String doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDose() {
        return dose;
    }

    public void setDose(String dose) {
        this.dose = dose;
    }
}
```

`fragment` of medicines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/medicinesList"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:text="@string/addmedButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`list` that contains the four text views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/medicineTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/doseTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/doctorTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

On previous implementation when I had two values and two text views I did something like that using `HashMap`

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    getActivity(),listItems,R.layout.list_item,
    new String[]{"name","id"},
    new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2});

Iterator it = patientInfoForList.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  HashMap<String,String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
  Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
  resultsMap.put("name",pair.getKey().toString());
  resultsMap.put("id",pair.getValue().toString());
  listItems.add(resultsMap);
}

patientsList.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

But with four values I can't figure it out. I tried using `HashMap<String,Medicine>` but I couldn't `put` the four values to the map. A cheap solution would be to concatenate the four strings into two and reduce the text views from four to two as well. But that will be my last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) instead of the SimpleAdapter.

I.e:

```
public class MedicinesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Medicine> {
    public MedicinesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Medicine> medicines) {
        super(context, 0, medicines);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Medicine medicine = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        TextView medicineTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.medicineTextView);
        TextView doseTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doseTextView);
        .... // Lookup  the rest of views for data population

        medicineTextView.setText(medicine.getName());
        doseTextView.setText(medicine.getDose());
        ... // Populate the rest of the views 
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here's a [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) to a good guide on the subject.  Make sure the read the part about the [ViewHolder pattern](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#improving-performance-with-the-viewholder-pattern).

Comment: Exactly what I need